# awk to match lines using partial match and print message

Tags: awk

I am trying to use the `awk` below to match the line in `file1` to the line in`file2` using a partial match.  If the string matches partially to another, then a custom output (`.... missing but ... found`) is printed for that line.

Currently, the name be searched for displays missing as it is not ann exact match.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
ID
NAME
MRE11
```

**file2**

```
NAME
ID
MRE11A
```

**desired output**

```
2 ids found
MRE11 missing but MRE11A found
```

**awk**

```
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]+|-" }
NR == FNR { seen[$1]; next }
$1 in seen { found[$1]; delete seen[$1] }
END { print length(found) " ids found"
  for (i in seen) print i " missing" }
```

Maybe:

```
else print (i in seen) "missing" but i found }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               {if($1 in a) c++; 
                else for(k in a) 
                        if(k~$1) {print $1,"missing but found",k; break}} 
       END     {print c,"ids matched"}' file2 file1

MRE11 missing but found MRE11A
2 ids matched
```

to change the order, you need to keep the matched ones in an array and print at the END block as well.  However, this seems easier.